# exact array using ES 6 from an array of object

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm working with Angular 5 http Client to fetch data from an API. This is my subscribe part

```
vehicles: Vehicle[];
getVehicleList() {
this.vehicleService.getVehicleData()  
.subscribe(data => { 
    this.vehicles = data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));} 
)
}
```

Vehicle interface

```
  export interface Vehicle {
    type: string;
 }
```

I'm getting an JSON look like this

```
       {
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "bus"
    },
    {
      "type": "truck"
    },
    {
      "type": "car"
    }
  ],
  "_metadata": null
}
```

I want to get only array from above using map function. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: What about `data.data`?

Comment: @KhauriMcClain - I tried that too.. getting error in IDE as [ts] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Vehicle[]'

Comment: then change your interface?

Comment: Are you sure `this.vehicles = data.data` doesn't work? Or are you accidentally doing `this.vehicles.data = ...`?

Comment: No I tried what you wrote. getting error as Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Vehicle[]' –

Comment: I defined the array as data: Array<string>; or  data: string[] like this. but still getting the error [ts] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Vehicle[]'

Comment: how does the service code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are asking here, but as Khauri pointed out, you can get the data array by using `data.data`.
If you want to use map on top of it, it would look like this :

```
data.data.map(element => console.log(element.type))
```

This would pritnt

> bus
>   truck
>   car

[EDIT] If you just want to get the array, you should just use `data.data`
Assuming you are using typescript, you need to add to your `Vehicule` interface a `data` field, which is an array.

Comment: Why map instead of a forEach?

Comment: Also this won't return something it will just log

Comment: @Alexandre Rozier- I defined the arry as data: Array<string>; or  data: string[] like this. but still getting the error [ts] Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Vehicle[]'

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the solution of the comments before should work.

Please make sure, that you changed your code to the following:

```
    vehicles: Vehicle[];
    getVehicleList() {
        this.vehicleService.getVehicleData()
        .subscribe(data => { 
             this.vehicles = data.data;
        })
    }
```

Comment: It's already given as an answer. See my reply to that as well

Comment: can you add some lines of your `verhicleService.getVehicleData()` function?